# what are the ways to create dialog boxes in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I would like to know what are the ways to create the dialog box in angular. What I came to know is `$modal and $dialog` are used to create dialog boxes. Is `$dialog` service is deprecated in recent versions of angular? Is there the alternative to the `$modal`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the modal libs from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. I have been using them to create my dialogs for the past year, no fuss

Comment: Is $modal the only way of creating dialog boxes in the recent version of angular js?

Comment: as far as i know, other than plain javascript dialogs, yes